# telethon: send message containing photo with bot

Tags: python, telethon

I need to send a photo that already exists on telegram servers with a bot using telethon, but telethon returns this error:

```sh
The provided media object is invalid or the current account may not be able to send it (such as games as users) (caused by SendMediaRequest)
```

the telegram bots are able to do so, I have used the same bot, in nodejs ( and telegrafjs ) to do such a thing, I know telegram allows bots to send photos and other types of media

and here is the official telegram docs for this:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

I use this code for bot initialize and send a message:

```py
bot = TelegramClient(bot_name, API_ID, API_HASH)

bot.start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

# this part is in am async function
bot.send_message(destination_id, message)
```

and here is the message ( its constructed by telethon itself ):

```sh
Message(id=1077, to_id=PeerChannel(channel_id=1262793861), date=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 15, 22, 42, 21, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='ggg', out=True, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=True, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False, from_id=None, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, media=MessageMediaPhoto(photo=Photo(id=5013054612525131926, access_hash=7495255942825644027, file_reference=b'\x04KD\xb4\x85\x00\x00\x045_\xb1\xae\xcdb\xf6-\xbdRe\x8d\x95\xecl\x00g\xd0N\x04*', date=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 15, 22, 42, 21, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), sizes=[PhotoStrippedSize(type='i', bytes=b'\x01\x17({^\xb8\xe8\x82\x83q9\xe8\xb8\x1e\xb8\xac\xe9ZO;\x86\n\x07L\x9a\xbb\x0c\xe6y\n\x92v\xe0\x1c\x8e\xe7\x02\xa1E\xb3F\xd1p9 \x1c\xd3X\x93RF\x9b\xa3S\x9e\xa2\x86\x8f\x83\xcd_+&\xe8\xaeM\x14\x8ch\xa2\xc1r\xa6\xa9\x08B\x8c\xbd1\x8f\xca\xa7\x86\r\x91\xa9$g`\xe8:QEib.Yi\x04q\x96$\x80\xa3<V\x1c\xf34\xd2\x17by<\x0fJ(\xa0\x07\xdb\xdc\xb4$n\xf9\x93\xb84QE+\x81'), PhotoSize(type='m', location=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=806528141, local_id=255612), w=320, h=180, size=11276), PhotoSize(type='x', location=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=806528141, local_id=255613), w=800, h=449, size=37459), PhotoSize(type='y', location=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=806528141, local_id=255610), w=1280, h=719, size=69452)], dc_id=1, has_stickers=False, video_sizes=[]), ttl_seconds=None), reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=1, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None, restriction_reason=[])
```

and I user telethon `v 1.16.4`

Comment: If `message` is the `Message` object you show, make sure this object was produced by the same bot account and not other.

Comment: @Lonami Don't bots have access to file objects sent by other people?

Comment: What I mean is that the same account that was used to access a file must send the file (the file can be from anyone though). You can also just pass the entire `.media` object to `send_file` and it will work.